# Problem with exporting lists to Excel

Tags: export, list-manipulation, excel

When I use the form `Export["file", list, "Table"]` to export a list to Excel, I get columns of lists. I want my Excel sheet to have each list element in a separate column.

For example,

```
Export["file.xls", {{2, 5}, {5, 7}}, "Table"]
```

Gives the output

> ```
> {2,5}
> {5,7}
> ```

I want those lists above to be split up. How do I do this?

Comment: `Flatten` will get rid of the nesting and will give you one column. Not sure how to transpose it. `Export["file.xls", Flatten@{{2, 5}, {5, 7}}, "Table"]`

Comment: There appears to be some confusion about the format of the desired output. Please provide a sample.

Answer (score 3):

Correct it to be:

```
Export["file.xls",{{2,5},{5,7}}]
```

or more explicitly

```
Export["file.xls",{{2,5},{5,7}},"XLS"]
```

`"Table"` is a generic Table-Format, suitable for a simple Text-Editor, not specially dedicated to Excel

When you leave away the 3rd argument, then the default value is `"XLS"`, and Excel will import it without additional Import-Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
tab = {{2, 5}, {5, 7}};
tab2 = List /@ # & /@ tab  (* or tab2 = Map[List,tab,{-1}] *)
(*  {{{2},{5}},{{5},{7}}} *)
Export["fileA.xls", tab2]
```

[image]

[image]