# Exporting row vector as a column in excel

Tags: data, excel

I want to export a vector in Mathematica to appear as a column in Excel. I am trying

```
A={1, 2, 3}; 
Export["mfile.xls", {"A" -> A}]
```

But it is showing 1,2,3 in a row in the Excel file. I tried

```
Export["mfile.xls", {"A" -> Column[A]}]
```

But it is messed up as well.
Any way to do this?

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aA = {1, 2, 3};

Export["mfile2.xls", {"A" -> List/@ aA}]
```

[image]

or

```
Export["mfile2b.xls", {"A" -> Transpose@{aA}}]
```

[image]

see also this related Q/A: [Problem exporting lists to Excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52309/125)

Comment: Note the "A" here is the sheet name not the column ( "A" might not have been the best choice for the example.. )

Comment: @george2079, i agree some other sheet name would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

```
Export["C:\\YourPath\\test.xlsx", List /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```